# How could I run a child java process in Windows?

Tags: java, c, winapi, process

I have a Windows program written in **C** (let's say, a `launcher`) and a javaFX-based application packed in `*jar` (a `payload`). What I want to do is to achieve something similar to how JetBrains's IntelliJ IDEA behaves. I mean, in the task manager we can see a process 'tree' or 'folder' like this:
[image: Windows Task Manager]

However in my case I see two completely independent processes: the `launcher.exe` (only in the `[Details]` section) and a `Java (TM) Platform SE binary` in the `[Processes]` section (actually it's my `payload`).

I am using a `CreateProcessW` function to spawn my process. In my code:

```
STARTUPINFOW info = { sizeof(info) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;

CreateProcessW(L"C:\\Path\\To\\java.exe", L" -jar C:\\Path\\To\\payload.jar",
    NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo);
```

How can I make my java application look more "native" in the Task Manager? I am using `jdk1.8.0_172`. Thanks for help.

Comment: Not sure this would change anything, but you are calling `CreateProcess` in a subtly unusual way: When you supply both an application name and command line argument, the spawned process receives the argument as its zeroth command line argument (as opposed to its first, as is conventional with C programs). Try moving everything into the command line (properly quoting the arguments) and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a process 'tree' or 'folder' like displayed in task manager you need meet the following two requirements:

1. The processes in a tree are executing the same program/application (grouped by app).
2. There is parent-child relationship among these processes. There is a parent process launches other processes those are child processes. (To check the parent-child relationship you can use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) tool.)

For your case, although the launcher.exe and java.exe (payload.jar) have the parent-child relationship but are not the same program/application so they can't be in a process 'tree' or 'folder' in task manager.

Refer to "[About Processes and Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/about-processes-and-threads)" "[Child Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/child-processes)"

To demonstrate how to create a process 'tree' I create the following demo: a win32 console application. (Launch the TestGroupProcesses.exe, every time you press the Enter it will create a child process in the process tree.)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    printf("Press Enter to create the child process\n");

    while (getchar() != '\n');

    // Start the child process. 
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        GetCommandLine(),        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        )
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

The process 'tree' created by above demo look like this:

[image]